# Passing locals from partial view to another partial view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, erb

I want pass all passed `locals` from one partial view to 0-N inner partial views.

**Example:**

```
# my_view.html.erb
<%= render partial: 'my_partial_view', locals: { ...dynamic amount of variables... } %>
...
# _my_partial_view.html.erb
<%= render partial: 'inner_partial_view_A', locals: ??? if ABC %>
<%= render partial: 'inner_partial_view_B', locals: ??? if DEF %>
<%= render partial: 'inner_partial_view_C', locals: ??? if XYZ %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following

```
<%= render partial: 'inner_partial_view_A', local_assigns if ABC %>
<%= render partial: 'inner_partial_view_B', local_assigns if DEF %>
<%= render partial: 'inner_partial_view_C', local_assigns if XYZ %>
```